# Dynamically Source Bash & Profile Files Across Multiple Enviornments

Tags: bash, bashrc, source

I'd like to come up with a way to always source the user's profile and bash configuration files upon a interactive login or non-interactive login despite what file structure they may have. It would also be nice for it not to matter which flavor of Linux is installed on the machine.

For example, not everyone has a ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile file, but if they do they should be sourced.

My initial thought would be something like this (this is being run programmatically after a ssh):

```
[ -r /etc/profile ] && . /etc/profile;[ -r ~/.bash_profile ] && . ~/.bash_profile;[ -r ~/.profile ] && . ~/.profile;[ -r ~/.bashrc ] && . ~/.bashrc; OTHER COMMANDS...
```

However, this isn't quite working as I planned. The functions from the .bashrc file do not seem to be loaded in.

I appreciate any help! Thanks.

*Edit: Adding full SSH command*

```
ssh -p 22 dev@123 '[ -r /etc/profile ] && source /etc/profile;[ -r ~/.bash_profile ] && source ~/.bash_profile;[ -r ~/.profile ] && source ~/.profile;[ -r ~/.bashrc ] && source ~/.bashrc;cd ~/apps/my-project/;npm install;bower install;grunt production;~/start-apps.sh;' In my case, the command 'grunt' isn't being found because it's initiated in the .bashrc file.
```

Comment: How is this being run? Is `.bash_profile` being run?

Comment: SSH runs a login shell, so the `profile` files should be sourced anyway.

Comment: @Barmar It's being run after the ssh. e.g. 
    ssh dev@123 [ -r /etc/profile ] && . /etc/profile;[ -r ~/.bash_profile ] && . ~/.bash_profile;[ -r ~/.profile ] && . ~/.profile;[ -r ~/.bashrc ] && . ~/.bashrc; OTHER COMMANDS...

Comment: Is it in quotes? If not, everything after `&&` will run on the client, not the server. Please update the question with the actual command.

Comment: @Barmar ssh -p 22 dev@123 '[ -r /etc/profile ] && source /etc/profile;[ -r ~/.bash_profile ] && source ~/.bash_profile;[ -r ~/.profile ] && source ~/.profile;[ -r ~/.bashrc ] && source ~/.bashrc;cd ~/apps/my-project/;npm install;bower install;grunt production;~/start-apps.sh;'  

In my case, the command 'grunt' isn't being found because it's initiated in the .bashrc file.

Comment: Please put it in the question so you can format it properly.

Comment: Is it an alias? Aliases aren't normally expanded in non-interactive shells. Are other commands in `.bashrc` being executed? If you put `set -x` in there, do you see all the commands being echoed?

Comment: @Barmar No, this isn't an alias. However, I believe I found the issue which is quite obvious. The first line of this .bashrc file is this: "[ -z "$PS1" ] && return".. Meaning, if not running interactively, don't do anything. Which brings up a new question - Would simply setting PS1 solve the issue? This command is being spawned using forkpty using this node.js library: https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/

Comment: Yes, setting `PS1` would solve that problem, but might produce others, if the `.bashrc` does things that require a terminal. You may also need the `-t` option to `ssh`.